# backbone fetch url data formatting error

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js

I am using a backbone collection to fetch some data. in my options passed into fetch I have a string parameter that is added to the url:

```
options = {data: {sterm: "hello world"}}
```

when backbone runs the fetch on this the url contains

```
sterm=hello+world
```

which isn't accepted by the backend it needs to be of the format:

```
sterm=hello%20world
```

so I changed the options to:

```
options = {data: {sterm: encodeURIComponent("hello world")}}
```

then when the fetch is executed it contains the correctly formatted query parameter, however if I pass in a string with a % in it, then encodeURIComponent seems to change % for %25 which I understand is correct, but then inside backbone fetch it gets changed to %2525 which is wrong. Is there any way to configure backbones fetch so it doesnt chagne %25 to %2525?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Backbone` collection `fetch()` method [uses](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) `jQuery.ajax()` method and accepts `jQuery.ajax()` options as parameters. In jQuery.ajax() method's [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you may find that if you define `processData` field to `false`, there will be no pre-processing of the data in the request.

```
options = {
    data: {
        sterm: encodeURIComponent("hello world")
    },
    processData: false
}
```