# Backbone fetch url not formatting as expected

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-encoding

It is similar to [backbone fetch URL data formatting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631959/backbone-fetch-url-data-formatting-error) except that when trying the answer the URL looks like `http://localhost?site:[Object%20Object]`

My data:

```
options.data = { name:companyName}
```

Where company name would hold a value like `"One, Two, Three"`. Without doing the `encodeURIComponent`, the query looks like `http://localhost?name=One%2C+Two%2C+Three`.

I would have expected it to look like `http://localhost?name=One%2C%20Two%2C%20Three` (note the `%20` in the URL and the removal of `+`).

Just to be clear my code looks something like this:

```
 sync: function(method, model, options) {
    switch(method){
        case "read": {
              options.data = { name:options.data.name} //I only want to pass in a subset of properties for the query.
              //options.data = {encodeURIComponent(options.data.name)} //this returns [Object%20Object]
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

I have tried `processData:` either being `false` or `true` for both scenarios.

## Update

I'm currently getting around this by doing the following:

```
sync:function(method, model, options){  
    switch(method){  
        case "read":  
            options.url = this.url+"?name="+options.data.name  
            break;  
        default:
            break;
    }  
    Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);  
}
```

That gets me my expected result I just can't believe that this is the answer and that backbone just cannot handle sequential special characters in a get request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fetch like the following automatically use `/test?name=One%2C%20Two%2C%20Three`. `encodeURIComponent` is not needed.

```
collection.fetch({
  data: {
    name: "One, Two, Three"
  }
});
```

```js
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: "test"
});

var collection = new Collection();

collection.fetch({
  data: {
    name: "One, Two, Three"
  }
});
// request to /test?name=One%2C%20Two%2C%20Three
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

From the [jQuery `ajax` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See `processData` option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs.

If you can't pass it as an option to the `fetch` function, you should override the `fetch` function of the collection (or model) instead of the `sync`.

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: "test",
  fetch: function(options) {
    options = options || {};
    // example, extending the data object.
    options.data = _.extend({}, options.data, { name: this.companyName });
    return Collection.__super__.fetch.call(this, options);
  }
});
```

Comment: That's what I would expect but that is not what's happening. In my question I stated that the url being built is http://localhost?name=One%2C+Two%2C+%2CThree  it's encoding the comma and removing the space and adding a "+"

Comment: @S.Will I include a code snippet in my answer which demonstrate it works. Maybe you're using another version of jQuery?

Comment: Ah, yes well this is embarrassing, i'm helping out on a web project it didn't realize they are still using Jquery 1.9. I'll see about updating it thanks!